# Why doesn't my code for extracting the first principal component work?

Tags: r, pca

Following [the Wikipedia article on PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#First_component), I extract the weights of the first principal component by calculating

$$\textbf{w}_1 = \mathrm{\arg\ max} \left\{ \frac{\textbf{w}^\intercal \textbf{X}^\intercal \textbf{X} \textbf{w}}{\textbf{w}^\intercal \textbf{w}} \right\}.$$

However, my R code for doing so with doesn't seem to correspond with the output of R's `prcomp()` function.

```
# Set seed
set.seed(1)

# Initialize and scale data
X = diag(10)
X = scale(X)

# Define objective function
objec = function(w){ (t(w)%*%t(X)%*%X%*%w)/(t(w)%*%w) }

# Run optimization with Nelder--Mead method
o = optim(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), objec, 
          control=list(maxit=10000, fnscale=-1), method="Nelder-Mead")

# Check output
print(o)

# Print out output of optimization
o$par

# Print out output of prcomp()'s first principal component
prcomp(X)$rotation[, 1]
```

What's going on?

Comment: Given that this has a good (& software-neutral) answer, I think it could stay open here.

Comment: Be aware that code-check (& exclusively software usage) questions are off topic here. In light of that, you would do best to suplement or re-write your code using mathematical notation or pseudocode.

Comment: This vector `X` has *nine* "first" principal components!  The eigenspace for the largest eigenvalue has nine dimensions.  It would be a miracle if any two different--but fully correct--algorithms were to produce the same bases for them.  Try a random symmetric matrix instead.  BTW, here's a simpler algorithm. The last line finds the eigenvalue. `w <- rnorm(dim(X)[1]);
v <- abs(w) + 1;
while(crossprod(v-w) > 1e-16) {
  v <- w;
  w <- X %*% w;
  w <- w / sqrt(sum(w*w))
};
(w);
(X %*% w) / w`

Comment: @whuber Yes! That is the true issue here. +1.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment below my answer "Yeah, not being an R guy, i didn't pay attention to the particular value of X until after I posted my answer, but even for a "joe average" X (in the best case), everything I wrote applies."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're using is an absolutely horrid and unreliable method for computing the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $X^TX$. Both in formulation and in choice of optimization algorithms (Nelder-Mead? Seriously? This is the 21st century.)

Your optimization may not have converged, and if it did, it, it may have converged to the wrong answer.

If it did converge to the solution of the problem as input to the optimizer, it is only unique to within a scale factor applied to the solution w.  This lack of uniqueness is one of only several things complicating your optimization.  If you divide each component of your "optimal" w by $\sqrt{(w^Tw)}$, then it will have unit norm, as does the output of prcomp(X)$rotation[, 1], and is unique to within a scale factor of +/-1, and it is "arbitrary" which of these (+/-1) is chosen.

So in short, if your solution w, divided by $\sqrt{(w^Tw)}$ matches the output of prcomp(X)$rotation[, 1], or the negative of this output, then you have obtained agreement.  If it doesn't, then your solution is wrong.

If you provide the (+ or -) unit norm eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $X^TX$ as a starting value to your optimizer, hopefully it will "converge" to the correct solution, i.e., stay roughly where it started.  As your starting point moves further from the solution, the optimizer will have more difficulty converging to the correct solution.  I don't know what starting point your optimization is using, but note that w equal to the vector of zeros, which is the most common default value of starting point, could be problematic given your objective function.

Did you run optim with highest (most detailed) level of information output?  If not, you should. What does it say? Not that I would trust much coming from Nelder-Mead regarding convergence.

The point of your whole exercise should be only pedagogical, i.e., to illustrate why this is not a good approach, and you should use ready made, purpose-built algorithms (at least at the eigenvector or preferably singular vector level, if not principal component) for actual computation in which you want to reliably get the answer.

Comment: I knew it was @MarkLStone from the first line.

Comment: @Matthew Drury  There's no shortage of bad numerical methods. I still remember my 10th grade Algebra II teacher (RIP) telling us that computers solve systems of linear equations using Cramer's rule (determinants), because they're not smart enough to do elimination. Yeah, maybe when he programmed the computers. In the interest of fairness (A --> B does not imply B --> A), maybe when a post starts as this one does, it must be mine, but many of my posts, even those related to numerical methods or optimization, do not start in such a fashion at all.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Indeed. Stimulated by this eloquent answer, I opened the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) on Nelder-Mead and saw it starting with "The Nelder–Mead method or downhill simplex method or amoeba method"... Amoeba method!

Comment: Having said that, I strongly suspect that the quality of Nelder-Mead algorithm has *nothing* to do with the issue at hand. See whuber's comment to OP for what is probably the real issue here.

Comment: Yeah, not being an R guy, i didn't pay attention to the particular value of X until after I posted my answer, but even for a "joe average" X (in the best case), everything I wrote applies.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clarifying answer. I'm embarrassed by the fact that I used `diag(10)` as a testing matrix, but did indeed run into similar problems with matrices that didn't have any multiplicities in the eigenvalues. I'll certainly take a look at how some more advanced optimization methods perform.